# Selecting items in an array by using 2 coordinates and fill it

Tags: python, numpy

I'm making a Battleship game bot for a Discord server. I haven't implemented the Discord part yet and I'm still at making the game's logic.

This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import re

waters = np.zeros((10,10),'U2')

headers = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

#PRINTS THE BOARD
for i,header in enumerate(headers):
    if i == 0:
        print('    ',end='')
    print(header + '  ',end='')
    if i == len(headers)-1: print()

for x,line in enumerate(waters):
    print('%2d'%(x),end='')
    for pos in line:
        if pos == '':
            print(' ##',end='')
        else:
            print(' '+pos,end='')
    print()

board_x_coord = {
    "A":0,
    "B":1,
    "C":2,
    "D":3,
    "E":4,
    "F":5,
    "G":6,
    "H":7,
    "I":8,
    "J":9
}

ship_type = [
    ["CV","Carrier",5],
    ["BB","Battleship",4],
    ["CA","Cruiser",3],
    ["SS","Submarine",3],
    ["DD","Destroyer",2],
]

def board_coord_to_npcoord(ship,coord):
    result = re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9])',coord)
    try:
        if result[0] in headers:
            if int(result[1]) in range(0,9):
                if result[2] in headers:
                    if int(result[3]) in range(0,9):
                        x_crd_a = board_x_coord.get(result[0])
                        y_crd_a = int(result[1])
                        x_crd_b = board_x_coord.get(result[2])
                        y_crd_b = int(result[3])
                        print('X: %s , Y: %s , X: %s , Y: %s' %(x_crd_a,y_crd_a,x_crd_b,y_crd_b))
                        return True
        print('Error. Try again.')   
    except ValueError:
        print('Error. Try again.')
        return False

for ship in ship_type:
    while True:
        print('Coordinates for %s (%s): ' %(ship[1],ship[2]),end='')
        if board_coord_to_npcoord(ship[0],input()): break
```

The board looks like this:

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
 0 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 1 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 2 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 3 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 4 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 5 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 6 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 7 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 8 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 9 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
```

The script will ask for coordinates. Ex. Carrier: A0E0, Battleship: A2A5

```
   A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
 0 CV CV CV CV CV ## ## ## ## ##
 1 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 2 BB ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 3 BB ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 4 BB ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 5 BB ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 6 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 7 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 8 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
 9 ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ## ##
```

How can I fill the selected elements with corresponding ship type and also how can I detect collision?

Comment: There are few things i would add/change, first use regex that is more specific, next validate distance between inserted vales,  that will make rest easier, I'll look into all of that when i have a moment

Comment: just changing regex to `r'([A-J])(\d)([A-J])(\d)'` replaces all the nested if statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the first case and few minor changes:

- improved regex
- use '##' as default value for board cell
- print board changed into function

```
import numpy as np
import re

waters = np.full((10,10), '##','U2')
headers = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

#PRINTS THE BOARD
def printBoard():
    for i,header in enumerate(headers):
        if i == 0:
            print('    ',end='')
        print(header + '  ',end='')
        if i == len(headers)-1: print()

    for x,line in enumerate(waters):
        print('%2d'%(x),end='')
        [print(' '+pos,end='') for pos in line]
        print()

printBoard()

board_x_coord = {
    "A":0,
    "B":1,
    "C":2,
    "D":3,
    "E":4,
    "F":5,
    "G":6,
    "H":7,
    "I":8,
    "J":9
}

ship_type = [
    ["CV","Carrier",5],
    ["BB","Battleship",4],
    ["CA","Cruiser",3],
    ["SS","Submarine",3],
    ["DD","Destroyer",2],
]

def board_coord_to_npcoord(ship,coord):
    try:
        result = re.findall(r'([A-J])(\d)([A-J])(\d)',coord)[0]
        x_crd_a = board_x_coord.get(result[0])
        y_crd_a = int(result[1])
        x_crd_b = board_x_coord.get(result[2])
        y_crd_b = int(result[3])
        vertical = ship[2] == abs(x_crd_b - x_crd_a + 1) and y_crd_a == y_crd_b
        horizontal = ship[2] == abs(y_crd_b - y_crd_a + 1) and x_crd_a == x_crd_b
        valid = vertical or horizontal
        if valid == False:
            print('Invalid length')
            return False
        if vertical:
            waters[y_crd_a][x_crd_a:x_crd_b + 1] = ship[0] 
            print(waters[y_crd_a][x_crd_a:x_crd_b])
            printBoard()
        print('X: %s , Y: %s , X: %s , Y: %s' %(x_crd_a,y_crd_a,x_crd_b,y_crd_b))
        return True
    except ValueError:
        print('Error. Try again.')
        return False

for ship in ship_type:
    while True:
        print('Coordinates for %s (%s): ' %(ship[1],ship[2]),end='')
        if board_coord_to_npcoord(ship,input()): break
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the inputs. Now it accepts 1 coordinate (X,Y) and orientation (H,V). If `H`, it will fill from the left to right starting from the given coordinate and also the same for `V` but this time it's up to bottom.

And also it doesn't care if there're space in the input Ex. `A   0     H` it will still be valid as long as the pattern is matched.

```
import re
import numpy as np

class PlaceToBoardError(Exception):
    pass

waters = np.full((10, 10), 'WW','U2')
headers = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']

ship_type = [
    ["CV","Carrier",5],
    ["BB","Battleship",4],
    ["CA","Cruiser",3],
    ["SS","Submarine",3],
    ["DD","Destroyer",2],
]

board_x_coord = {
    "a":0,
    "b":1,
    "c":2,
    "d":3,
    "e":4,
    "f":5,
    "g":6,
    "h":7,
    "i":8,
    "j":9
}

def printBoard():
    for i,header in enumerate(headers):
        if i == 0:
            print('    ',end='')
        print(header + '  ',end='')
        if i == len(headers)-1: print()

    for x,line in enumerate(waters):
        print('%2d'%(x),end='')
        [print(' '+pos,end='') for pos in line]
        print()

def collision_detect(selected_waters):
    if any(water != 'WW' for water in selected_waters): 
            return True
    return False

def place_to_board(ship,coord):
    try:
        pattern = r'(?i)\s*([a-j])\s*(\d)\s*([hv])'
        result = re.match(pattern,coord)
        if result == None: 
            raise PlaceToBoardError('Invalid coordinates. Please try again.')
        x_coord = board_x_coord.get(result[0][0].lower())
        y_coord = int(result[0][1])
        orientation = result[0][2].lower()

        if orientation == 'h':
            selected_waters = waters[y_coord,x_coord:ship[2]+x_coord]
            if collision_detect(selected_waters): 
                raise PlaceToBoardError('A ship is already placed in those waters. Please try again.')
            if len(selected_waters) == ship[2]:
                waters[y_coord,x_coord:ship[2]+x_coord] = ship[0]
            else:
                raise PlaceToBoardError('Not enough space. Please try again.')
        elif orientation == 'v':
            selected_waters = waters[y_coord:ship[2]+y_coord:,x_coord]
            if collision_detect(selected_waters): 
                raise PlaceToBoardError('A ship is already placed in those waters. Please try again.')
            if len(selected_waters) == ship[2]:
                waters[y_coord:ship[2]+y_coord:,x_coord] = ship[0]
            else:
                raise PlaceToBoardError('Not enough space. Please try again.')
        return True
    except PlaceToBoardError as ptbe:
        print(ptbe)
        return False
printBoard()
for ship in ship_type:
    while True:
        print('Coordinates for %s (%s): ' %(ship[1],ship[2]),end='')
        if place_to_board(ship,input()): 
            printBoard()
            break
```