# Better item placement in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm making a Battleship game bot for a Discord server. I haven't done the discord part yet but I completed the human input part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562212/selecting-items-in-an-array-by-using-2-coordinates-and-fill-it/58563417#58563417).

Now I'm making the bot that will place each ship on the water which is a numpy array.

This is the code for the bot.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import random

water_text = 'WW'

waters = np.full((10, 10), water_text, 'U2')
headers = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']

ship_type = [
    ["CV", "Carrier", 5],
    ["BB", "Battleship", 4],
    ["CA", "Cruiser", 3],
    ["SS", "Submarine", 3],
    ["DD", "Destroyer", 2],
]

board_x_coord = {
    "a": 0,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 2,
    "d": 3,
    "e": 4,
    "f": 5,
    "g": 6,
    "h": 7,
    "i": 8,
    "j": 9
}

possible_neighbor_count = 1


def printBoard():
    for i, header in enumerate(headers):
        if i == 0:
            print('    ', end='')
        print(header + '  ', end='')
        if i == len(headers)-1:
            print()

    for x, line in enumerate(waters):
        print('%2d' % (x), end='')
        [print(' '+pos, end='') for pos in line]
        print()


def collision_detect(selected_waters):
    if any(water != water_text for water in selected_waters):
        return True
    return False


def neighbor_counter(a, b):
    dist = 1
    return sum([y != water_text for w in [row[max(0, a-dist):a+dist+1] for row in waters[max(0, b-1):b+dist+1]] for y in w])-1


def neighbor_test(x, y, size, orientation):
    if orientation == 'H':
        neighbor_count = 0
        for i in range(size):
            x += i
            neighbor_count += neighbor_counter(x, y)
        return neighbor_count

    elif orientation == 'V':
        neighbor_count = 0
        for i in range(size):
            y += i
            neighbor_count += neighbor_counter(x, y)
        return neighbor_count


def no_neighbors(possible, size, orientation):
    neighbor_grades = []
    for nx,ny in possible:
        grade = neighbor_test(nx, ny, size, orientation)
        neighbor_grades.append((grade, (nx,ny)))
    return [y for x, y in neighbor_grades if x < possible_neighbor_count]


def get_available_waters():
    availables = []
    for y_pos, row in enumerate(waters):
        for x_pos, water in enumerate(row):
            if water == water_text:
                availables.append((x_pos, y_pos))
    return availables


def place_ship(ship):
    size = ship[2]
    orientation = random.choice(['H', 'V'])
    if orientation == 'H':
        possible = []
        for x, y in get_available_waters():
            selected_waters = waters[y, x:size+x]
            if len(selected_waters) == size:
                if not collision_detect(selected_waters):
                    possible.append((x, y))
        result = random.choice(no_neighbors(possible, size, orientation))
        px, py = result
        waters[py, px:size+px] = ship[0]

    elif orientation == 'V':
        possible = []
        for x, y in get_available_waters():
            selected_waters = waters[y:size+y:, x]
            if len(selected_waters) == size:
                if not collision_detect(selected_waters):
                    possible.append((x, y))
        result = random.choice(no_neighbors(possible, size, orientation))
        px, py = result
        waters[py:size+py:, px] = ship[0]


for ship in ship_type:
    place_ship(ship)

printBoard()
#print(waters)
```

Example output:

```
    A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J
 0 WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW
 1 WW WW CA CA CA WW WW WW WW WW
 2 WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW
 3 WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW
 4 WW WW WW CV WW WW WW SS WW WW
 5 WW WW BB CV WW WW WW SS WW WW
 6 WW WW BB CV WW WW WW SS WW WW
 7 WW WW BB CV WW WW WW WW WW WW
 8 WW WW BB CV WW DD DD WW WW WW
 9 WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW WW
```

The code above will:

1. Get a ship from list.
2. Choose the orientation for the placement.
3. Get unused positions.
4. Check if each unused position is possible for ship placement.
5. Place the ship.

The placement seems fine but sometimes the ships get too close to each other and that will result an easy game. How can I check if there's a neighboring ship? If there is, pick another position. Also, is there a better way to place each ship?

**Edit:** Added crude neighbor check.
Now I'm checking each possible position for neighbors
[image]

Comment: What would be a neighboring ship? Could you define it in mathematical terms?

Comment: @DanielMesejo This is how I check if there's a neighbor

`     x-1,y-1   x,y-1   x+1,y-1
  
  
  x-1,  y           x+1,  y
        
        
  x-1,y+1   x,y+1   x+1,y+1`

Comment: @DanielMesejo I added a very crude way to check if there's a neighboring ship. Now the ships won't get close to each other but my solution is very crude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at a subsection of the board and count neighbors, instead of checking each square separately.

Here is a shorter way to check neighbor count:

```
def neighbor_counter(a, b):
    x1, x2 = max(a-1, 0), min(a+2, 10)
    y1, y2 = max(b-1, 0), min(b+2, 10)
    return len([i for i in waters[y1:y2,x1:x2].flatten() if i != water_text])
```

However, you can implement the `neighbor_test` function without using `neighbor_counter` at all:

```
def neighbor_test(x, y, size, orientation):
    x1, y1 = max(x-1, 0), max(y-1, 0)
    x2, y2 = (min(x+size+1, 10), min(y+2, 10)) if orientation == "h" else (min(x+2, 10), min(y+size+1, 10))
    return len([i for i in waters[y1:y2,x1:x2].flatten() if i != water_text])
```

Or even better, you can implement the `no_neighbors` function without using `neighbor_test` at all:

```
def no_neighbors(possible,size,orientation):
    empty_spots=[]
    for x, y in possible:
        x1, y1 = max(x-1, 0), max(y-1, 0)
        x2, y2 = (min(x+size+1, 10), min(y+2, 10)) if orientation == "h" else (min(x+2, 10), min(y+size+1, 10))
        if all([i==water_text for i in waters[y1:y2,x1:x2].flatten()]):
            empty_spots.append(nei)
    return empty_spots
```

Note that in your function, ships at the top row can be neighbors with ships in the bottom row. The same is true for left and right columns. I'm assuming it is not intended, and my function is not considering these locations as neighbors.

Comment: How can I allow at least 1-2 neighbor ships? Your last function in your answer return all possible empty spots.

I modified my code in the question which allows neighbor by changing `possible_neighbor_count`'s value

Comment: I figured it out while also using your answer. Thank you.